# Views in Custom ListView item don't have apptheme

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, themes

**Problem:**

I have a custom adapter for my `listview` which currently contains a `checkbox` and an `edittext`. I haven't changed any themes in the `res/values/styles` folder. For some reason the `checkbox` and `edittext` have a different style/theme than the normal style/theme ("AppTheme").

Automatically generated theme:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

But the checkbox is white, and can only be seen when it is checked. (color is not the colorAccent set above) And the edittext has the same color the checkbox has when it is checked (green/blueish).

colors:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
```

**What have I tried?**

I tried setting the theme/style of the container of the item and the item itself, with the xml attributes `android:theme` and `style`. Each to no avail.

Is this normal? If so, how do I change the style/theme of the listitem? If not, what could be wrong?

My listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_listitem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_listitem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

getView in custom adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_note_checkbox, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_listitem);
        holder.editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText_listitem);
        convertView.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.editText.setText(items.get(position).note);
    return convertView;
}
```

screenshots:

[image: screenshot checkbox not checked]
[image: screenshot checkbox checked]

as we can see the radio buttons have the default layout, accentcolor "pink" and they have a grey outlining. but the checkbox outlining is white, and the accentcolor is blue/greenish.

Comment: If you have not set any style for your checkbox and edittext they will be shown as default. Am I missing something in your question? Could you post a small screenshot of what is actual and what is expected?

Comment: ok i will post screenshots in a moment

Comment: @MikeM. tried that, didn't work :/

Comment: Are you sure that `context` is the `Activity`'s `Context`? How are you initializing it? You might also use `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())`.

Comment: i tried `LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())` and it worked! but I called my adapter with `adapterclass(getApplicationContext(),null);` inside a listener, is this not correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's most likely why using `context` didn't work. You want to instantiate your `Adapter` with the `Activity`'s `Context` - e.g., `MyActivity.this` - instead of with `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: thanks! you can post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `Activity`'s `Context` for anything that requires styles and attribute values from its theme. Since your `Adapter`'s `context` field is initialized in its constructor, you need to instantiate your `Adapter` with the `Activity`'s `Context`, not the `Application`'s, so the `LayoutInflater` ends up with the correct one. For example:

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
```